# docplex issue: TypeError: Cannot use == to test expression equality, try using Python is operator or method equals:

Tags: python, docplex

```
mymodel = Model("OPL_Purchasing_plan");
nr_month= range(0, 12)
na_pur_req = [550, 750, 6500, 675, 210, 120, 0, 560, 140, 320, 0, 100]
na_average_cost = 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5, 12.5]

for i in nr_month:
    if(na_pur_req[i] == 0):
        mymodel.add_constraint(na_actual_cost_test[0][i] <= na_actual_suply[0][i] * 0,'con9');
     
    else:
        mymodel.add_constraint(na_actual_cost_test[0][i] <= na_actual_suply[0][i] * na_average_cost[i],'con10');
```

I am getting an error as follows

```
TypeError: Cannot use == to test expression equality, try using Python is operator or method equals
```

Why I am getting this error.

Comment: Your code does not compile and also you did not include the full backtrace, so we have no idea where your code may fail. Please provide a code that compiles and runs (your code has obvious syntax errors). Please also provide the backtrace so that we can identify the statement that fails.

Answer (score 0):

A DOcplex expression, built from decision variables and constants, is itself a decision object. Its value is defined only after a solve(), and can be queried by  the `solution_value` property.
Relational operators, such as `==`, `<=` and `>=` have been overloaded to generate *constraints*, for example x==1 is actually a constraint, not a Python boolean.
Writing code such as `if x==1` cannot work because x is actually a decision variable and has no value until solve.
This is why the message tells you you are attempting to test equality between two expressions. This could be done using `is` or method `equals`, but not with `==`.

Unfortunately, your code does not allow to reproduce the issue and understand why you are trying to do this.